# How to solve Jekyll-Include-Cache issue?

Tags: jekyll, bundle

I am currently trying to open an already created website made through Jekyll. I use the `cd` command through the terminal to get to the website file that I pulled from Github. Once I get to the file, I run `bundle exec Jekyll serve` and it shows this error message:

```
    Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have Jekyll-include-cache or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- Jekyll-include-cache' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
    Jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  Jekyll-include-cache
```

So I then do gem install Jekyll-include-cache and the issue remains. Does anyone know how to fix this??

Comment: Hi Sammy! I think it would be helpful for you to include more information on what website you're attempting to pull down and how (Github? Something else?) and more of the stack trace in your question. Also, I'd recommend using some of the formatting so it's a bit easier for people to parse. That way you're most likely to get the best answers from people who see your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that Jekyll couldn't load the plugin properly.
Ensure that you have listed the plugin in your Gemfile:

```ruby
# Gemfile

gem "jekyll-include-cache"
```